# Kotlin generics: counterintuitive type inference and checking with out keyword

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariant, generic-variance

I've been recently learning Kotlin, while having some questions with **covariant** type.

The sample code is here. 
I have `Option` and `Option2` both having a type parameter `T` and a `run` extension.

I could understand the first two `run` in `validation()`, since they are behaved as Java. 
But why does the third line compile? `Option<T>` is **invariant** in `T`. We cannot passing `Option<C>` instance into where `Option<B>` is expected.

After I add an `out` keyword for `T`, now all of them could compile. Why?

```java
open class A
open class B : A()
open class C : B()


class Option<T>(val item: T)

fun <T> Option<T>.run(func: (Int) -> Option<T>): Option<T> = func(1)


class Option1<out T>(val item: T) //out keyword

fun <T> Option1<T>.run(func: (Int) -> Option1<T>): Option1<T> = func(1)


fun validation() {
    val opt: Option<B> = Option(B())
    opt.run { Option(A()) } //won't compile as expected
    opt.run { Option(B()) } //return type is Option<B>
    opt.run { Option(C()) } //return type is Option<B>; why could this compile?

    val opt1: Option1<B> = Option1(B())
    opt1.run { Option1(A()) } //return type is Option<A>; why could this compile?
    opt1.run { Option1(B()) } //return type is Option<B>
    opt1.run { Option1(C()) } //return type is Option<B>
}
```

Comment: have you read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance? I think it's hard to put those words into something simpler.

Answer (score 4):

- > `opt.run { Option(C()) } //return type is Option<B>; why could this compile?`

  Here, you can approximate the behavior as follows by decomposing the call into the two lines that are type-checked separately:

  ```
  val func: (Int) -> Option<B> = { Option(C()) }
  opt.run(func)
  ```

  The first line is correct because:

  - the lambda is expected to return `Option<B>` (with exactly `B`, as `Option` is invariant),
  - so the `Option(item: T): Option<T>` constructor call needs to accept a `B`,
  - the argument that is passed is `C()`,
  - as `C : B`, `C()` passes the check for being `B`,
  - and so `Option(C())` can also be typed as `Option<B>` and passes the check,
  - OK, the lambda passes the check for `(Int) -> Option<B>`.

  Sanity check: what if you replace the first line as follows?

  ```
  val func: (Int) -> Option<B> = { Option(C()) as Option<C> }
  ```

  Then it won't get compiled, as the expression inside the lambda is now typed as `Option<C>` which is not a subtype of `Option<B>`.

---

- > `opt1.run { Option1(A()) } //return type is Option<A>; why could this compile?`

  In this sample, the type that the compiler chose for `T` is not `B`, it is `A`. The compiler is allowed to do that because of covariance of the type parameter `T`.

  - `opt1` is `Option1<B>`
  - `Option1<out T>` is covariant on `T`, which allows substituting `T` with any supertype of `B`,

    <sup>This is allowed because for any `Z` such that `B : Z`, `opt1` can also be treated as `Option1<out Z>` thanks to the `out` modifier, and the compiler can then type-check the call against a receiver type `Option1<Z>`.</sup>
  - the substition for `T` would be the least common supertype of `B` and whatever `X` such that the lambda returns `Option1<X>`,
  - the lambda returns `Option1<A>`,
  - find the least common supertype of `B` and `A`,
  - given that `B : A`, the least common supertype is `A`
  - substitute `T := A`.

  Sanity check: what if you change the expression as follows?

  ```
  opt1.run { Option1(0) }
  ```

  It will still compile successfully, but the inferred return type will be `Option1<Any>`. This is totally reasonable according to the above, because the least common supertype of `B` and `Int` is `Any`.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: this is not how the compiler works internally, but using this way of reasoning you may often get the results that agree with the compiler's results.</sup>

Comment: You really help me a lot to understand this question. Thanks!