# Kotlin - Generic Type Parameters Not Being Respected

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-inference, typechecking, type-parameter

Consider the following example:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1

infix fun <T, R> KProperty1<T, R>.test(value: R) = Unit

data class Foo(val bar: Int)

fun main() {
    Foo::bar test "Hello"
}
```

Given that `test` expects a `value` of type `R`, why in this context, where the property type is `Int`, does it allow me to pass a `String`?

Comment: Most likely it's inferred to be `Any`. At least this compiles: `Foo::bar.test<Foo, Any>("Hello")`, and it doesn't compile with `String` or `Int` instead of `Any`.

Comment: your problem seems to be related with the `out R`-definition on `KProperty1`... if that wasn't there, you would have your expected compile time error when passing a `String`...

Comment: I think the first sentence in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720842/4265739 answers your question

Comment: as a workaround (but there are probably nicer ways to support what you want), you may just pass the kproperty along to a producer-function, e.g.: `inline infix fun <T, U, R : U> KProperty1<T, U>.test(block : (KProperty1<T, U>) -> R) = block(this)` with a usage as follows: `Foo::bar test { 3 }`. This way the compiler will warn you if you return anything that differs from `R : U`... similar things can also be accomplished by using your own intermediate type holding the requested type... (e.g. `Foo::bar.toYourIntermediate() test 3`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, take a look at the declaration of the interface `KProperty1`, which is:

```
interface KProperty1<T, out R> : KProperty<R>, (T) -> R
```

The important part here is the [`out`-projected](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections)  type parameter `R`, which defines subptyping relationships between the `KProperty1` types with different type arguments used for `R`.

***(1)*** Namely, for any `Foo`, `A` and `B` such that `A : B` (`A` is a subtype of `B`), 
`KProperty1<Foo, A> : KProperty1<Foo, B>`. This is called covariance, because the parameterized types relate to each other in the same way as their type arguments do.

---

***(2)*** Next, note that for any `A` and `B` such that `A : B`, an instance of `A` can be passed as an argument to any `B`-typed parameter. Receiver parameters of extension functions are not different from normal parameters in this respect.

---

Now, the crucual part is the type inference algorithm that the compiler runs. One of the goals of type inference is to establish statically-known type arguments for each generic call where type arguments are omitted.

During type inference for the call `Foo::bar test "Hello"`, the compiler needs to actually infer the type arguments for `T` and `R` based on the known types of the receiver `Foo::bar` (`KProperty1<Foo, Int>`) and the `value` argument `"Hello"` (`String`).

This is done internally by solving a constraint system. We could emulate this logic as follows:

- Given that `KProperty<Foo, Int>` is passed as `KProperty<T, R>`:

  - we must use `T := Foo` (as `T` is invariant)
  - we must use `Int` or any of its supertypes as the type argument `R`

    - this is because of covariance for `R`: given ***(1)*** and ***(2)*** combined, choosing `Int` or some of its supertypes for `R` is necessary to be able to pass `KProperty<Foo, Int>` where `KProperty<Foo, R>` is expected
    - examples of these supertypes are `Int?`, `Number`, `Number?`, `Any`, `Any?`
- Given that a `String` is passed as `R`:

  - we must use `String` or some of its supertypes as `R`

    - this is necessary to be able to pass a `String` where `R` is expected due to ***(2)***
    - examples of these supertypes are `String?`, `CharSequence`, `CharSequence?`, `Any`, `Any?`

Given the two constraints on `R`, namely that it should be `Int` or some of its supertypes and it should be `String` or some of its supertypes, the compiler finds the least common type that satisfies both. This type is `Any`.

So, the inferred type arguments are `T := Foo` and `R := Any`, and the call with explicit type arguments would be:

```
Foo::bar.test<Foo, Any>("Hello")
```

<sup>In IntelliJ IDEA, you can use an action *Add explicit type arguments* on a non-infix call to add the inferred types.</sup>

---

<sup>Disclaimer: this is not exactly how the compiler works internally, but using this way of reasoning you may often get the results that agree with the compiler's results.</sup>

---

Also relevant:

- [Kotlin generics: counterintuitive type inference and checking with out keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765128/kotlin-generics-counterintuitive-type-inference-and-checking-with-out-keyword)
- [Generic extensions of KProperty1 in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717977/generic-extensions-of-kproperty1-in-kotlin/52720842#52720842)